# WPF xamdatagrid height + window size to content

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid, sizetocontent

I have window with SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight",startup location sets to manual.
This window contains one grid with two rows: first with height "1*" and second with auto height.
The first row contains xamdatagrid (infragistics) and the second contains OkCancel buttons.

after xamdatagrid initialization the window is been vertically stretched beyond visible area.

I don't want to bind max height to some calculation based on system parameters and other constants.

[See: Window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLSFQ.png)

code:

```
<Window x:Class="CopyRenameLineItems.CopyAndRename"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
         x:Name="CopyWindow" Title="Copy/Rename Line Item"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=copyRenameLineItems:CopyAndRenameViewModel}" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="7" Name="MainGrid">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <igDP:XamDataGrid Name="CopyRenameGrid" Margin="5" GroupByAreaLocation="None" DataSource="{Binding Rows,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            AutoFit="True" RecordContainerGenerationMode="PreLoad" >
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                <igDP:FieldSettings
                    CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource CellsBorder}"
                    AutoSizeOptions="All"
                AllowEdit="True"   
                AllowRecordFiltering="True"
                FilterLabelIconDropDownType ="MultiSelectExcelStyle" 
                CellClickAction="EnterEditModeIfAllowed"/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings 
                    AllowClipboardOperations="All"                                
                    AutoGenerateFields="False"
                    AutoFitMode="Never"
                    FilterRecordLocation="OnTop"                                
                    FilterUIType="LabelIcons"  />
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        <igDP:Field Name="Copy" >
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings Width="Auto" LabelPresenterStyle="{StaticResource CopyHeader}" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="Name" Label="Name"">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" Width="Auto" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="Description" Label="Description">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" Width="Auto"/>
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="NewName" Label="New name" Width="200">
                        </igDP:Field>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Height="25" Width="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                    Content="OK" Command="{Binding CopyRenameWindowOkButtonClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CopyWindow}" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column ="1">
            <Button Height="25" Width="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding  CloseWindowCancelButtonClick}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CopyWindow}"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks,

Zehavit

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: Added some code to the question, ignore namespaces I changed them so I can upload the code

Comment: Could you try to use `VerticalAlignment="Top"` on the root `Grid` element

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the value 1* doesn't mean anything with the SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight". If you change the "1*" to "Auto", you will have the same behavior. You should remove SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight" and do this :

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        your list ..
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        you buttons ..
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Your first row (list) will be (3/(3+1))% of the window size

The second (1/(3+1))%.

Comment: It's not the required behavior, I want the window height to fit the content, so if my list contains one row, the window height will shorter...

Answer (score 0):

***Don't use***

> SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"

alone cause it will set the `size` of `Window` as its content. And your `XamDataGrid` has many `records` so `Window` will grow to a very large size. instead just delete that property then the `content` will be adjusted according to `Window`.

***Or***

give your `Window` some `Height` first (as try `binding` the `Height` of your `Window` to ***`System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`***) then you can use ***`SizeToContent`*** and `Window` will not grow indefinitely.
Also `Grid` row heights are irrelevant cause you have not given any fixed `Height` to any `control` or `Grid`.

This solves the problem.